# Collision between two specific objects in unity

Tags: java, unity-game-engine

I have a problem when I try to load a new level when two objects collide. One of them is the player the other one is a moving part of the terrain.
For some reason I will not detect the colision between the two
Both objects have a rigidbody and a box collider 2d.

What can I do?

My script:

```
#pragma strict

 function OnCollisionEnter(col : Collision){
     if(col.gameObject.name == "Lava"){
     Debug.Log ("test");
         Application.LoadLevel("Youlose");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for one, is your game 2D or 3D. You state you have a rigid body which conforms to a 3D game and a box collider 2D which conforms to a 2D game.

Also, since you have a box collider 2D, you would call

```
 function OnCollisionEnter2D(col:Collision2D)
```

Comment: I will give you the "answer" when I can in 5 minutes